# App showing contact numbers three times

Tags: android

I have created an app in which when a button is clicked activity opens and the user has to select contact. All the numbers which contact has are displayed on the screen. Its working fine for contact having more than 3 numbers. But when a contact is selected which has one number , the app instead of showing the number one time shows the same numbers three times.

here is my code

```
    String contactNumber = "";
    if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0 ){
        Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + indexID, null,null);
        while(phoneCursor.moveToNext()){
            if(phoneCursor.getCount() > 1){
                contactNumber = contactNumber + "," + phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                contact_num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
                contact_num.setText(contactNumber);
            } else {
                contactNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                contact_num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
                contact_num.setText(contactNumber);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to put a break; at the end of (... > 1) block

Comment: Didnt worked! I broke multi number contacts also!